# Is there any way to apply field customizer to Thumbnails view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, spfx-extensions, fieldcustomizers

I want to apply the field customizer to both `Thumbnails view` and `Modern list view`. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: did you try using json column formatting ?

Comment: There is no column shown in Thumbnails view.